# How do I send a local toast in C

Tags: c, windows, toast

I have looking all over internet, but I cannot find any good documentation about windows 10 toast that are not written in C# or C++, I am not very familliar with C# and the dot net framework and it is giving me a bit of a headache. Could someone help me? Some links to good documentation on the subject would be fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that mmozeiko's TwitchNotify is a great example of utilizing the toast COM/WinRT API: [Implementation](https://github.com/mmozeiko/TwitchNotify/blob/master/WindowsToast.h). It references multiple documentation links through the code in case you want to deeply examine the topic.

Before reading into it though, I'd recommend taking some [COM classes](http://%20https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C) (pun not intended), if you haven't already.

However, don't get discouraged by ***horrible*** Windows APIs. Good luck!